# Set forecolor via html code in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I've got a grid view where I am trying to set the fore color from a database string which contains HTML Code.  I tried this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Validation">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblValidationItem" runat="server" ToolTip="Type of validation."
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ValidationItem") %>' Font-Bold="true" ForeColor='<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("HTMLColor")) %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

But it says FromHtml has some invalid parameters?

Comment: Just as an FYI HTMLCOlor in the database contains a string like `#FFFFFF`.

Comment: How is HTMLColor stored in the database?  What does it look like before trying to translate?  You probably need to convert it to the proper format before the databind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval returns an "Object".  You need to cast it to a string:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblValidationItem" runat="server" ToolTip="Type of validation."
                                        Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.ValidationItem") %>' Font-Bold="true" ForeColor='<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml((string)Eval("HTMLColor")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```